# Select all child divs with a certain width and update that width

Tags: jquery

I want to change all child divs(parent div id=product_list) with a width of `41%` to have a width of `31%`.

Is there any way in jquery to find the child divs with a width of `41%`(only under parent div id=product_list) and change the width to `31%`

**Note:** i cant set code child div id bocz those are change randomly very time.

this is html code

```
<div id="product_list" style="float:none;">
  <div id="row_4fec46be9210e" style="margin-right: 5px; width:31%; float:left;">
      <div id="row_4fec" style="margin-right: 5px; width:15%; float:left;"></div>
      <div id="row_4fec" style="margin-right: 5px; width:16%; float:left;"></div>
  <div>
  <div id="row_4fec46be92339" style="margin-right: 5px; width:31%; float:left;"></div>
  <div id="row_4fec46be92523" style="margin-right: 5px; width:31%; float:left;"></div>
  <div id="row_4fec46be92523" style="margin-right: 5px; width:41%; float:left;"></div>
  <div id="row_4fec46be92523" style="margin-right: 5px; width:41%; float:left;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Alnitak,bcoz 31% width working well with design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to query inline CSS attributes with a selector.

It would be far simpler to just overwrite every child div's `width` CSS property than to try to only change the ones with the "wrong" value:

```
$('#product_list > div').css('width', '31%');
```

The `>` in the selector ensures that this will only change the direct children of `#product_list`, and not their children too.

Comment: bcoz i dont want to change where child div width = 15% and 16%

Comment: @vikastyagi yes, my answer copes with that - the `>` in the selector means it only sets the width of the higher level divs, not the children.

Answer (score 5):

The following code snippets set the width of all child `divs` in all hierarchy.

```
$("#product_list div").css('width', '31%');
```

**Updated:**
And the following one will definitely solve your problem bu using jquery [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method

```
$("#product_list").children().css('width', '31%');
```

Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: sigh - 5 minutes late to the party, almost identical to another answer, and introduced a bug at the same time... :(

Comment: the answer isn't identical, you missed out my `>` (which is your bug).  and why post an answer that you believe to be identical to one already posted?  That's known as plagiarism.

Comment: @Alnitak I didn't copy and paste your code. Even u don't even bother to test my code either it is right or wrong. I know there is no selector '>' here. Its really very sad to know a person who is highly rated talk like this :(. The bug in my code is that it set the width of all child divs in all hierarchy. and now i am gonna edit this

Comment: you had a single line of code in your answer, with no explanatory text, and you even asserted that it was identical.  What was I supposed to think?!

Comment: I was in hurry yesterday. and the answer is self explanatory